# Updating ONLY one search param using react-router-dom Link

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination, react-router-dom, urlsearchparams

I want to navigate to the same route, but preserve all search params on link click and change only the `page`.

I am using Material-UI's `Pagination` component and React-Router-DOM's `Link`.

I have tried spreading the existng search params and changing only the `page`, but it removes all params and appends only the page one.

```
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';
import { useDataQuery } from '../../api';
import { itemsPerPage } from '../../constants';
import { PaginationItem } from '@mui/material';
import {
  Link,
  createSearchParams,
  useLocation,
  useSearchParams
} from 'react-router-dom';

export function PaginatedList() {
  const { data } = useDataQuery();
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  const currentPage = Number(searchParams.get('page')) || 1;
  const pageCount = data?.total ? Math.ceil(data?.total / itemsPerPage) : 1;

  return (
    <Box>
      <List>
        {data.items.map((dataItem) => (
          <ListItem key={dataItem.id}>
            <Card item={dataItem} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <Box>
        <Pagination
          defaultPage={1}
          page={currentPage}
          count={pageCount}
          renderItem={(item) => (
            <PaginationItem
              component={Link}
              to={{
                pathname: location.pathname,
                search:
                  item.page === 1
                    ? ''
                    : createSearchParams({
                        ...searchParams,
                        page: item.page?.toString(),
                      }).toString(),
              }}
              {...item}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I have also tried setting the query like this, but it does not seem to do anything (it is not appending any params to the pathname):

```ts
to={{
  pathname: location.pathname,
  query: {
    ...searchParams,
    page: item.page,
  },
}}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-router-link-pagination-52j4pr?file=%2Fsrc%2FPaginatedList.jsx%3A11%2C15) is the link to the working codesandbox demo.

Comment: @Drew Reese Hello, Thanks for the fast response. You understand it right. I want to navigate to the same route, but only change the `page` search param. Here is the  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-router-link-pagination-52j4pr?file=%2Fsrc%2FPaginatedList.jsx%3A11%2C15) you asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I realized you were mostly working with Material-UI components, so creating a sandbox of my own was pretty trivial. I've already provided an answer with my suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PaginationItem` component appears to close over a stale copy of the search params and it doesn't appear as though you can "intercept" the `Link` component's `onClick` event handler to manually handle the search params because it's the `PaginationItem` component's click handler that it needs to effect the page change.

Best suggestion I can think of is to use the `Pagination` component's [`onChange`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/pagination/#Pagination-prop-onChange) handler to synchronize the URL search params to the changed page value.

Example:

```
<Pagination
  defaultPage={1}
  page={currentPage}
  count={pageCount}
  onChange={(e, page) => {
    setSearchParams((searchParams) => {
      if (page === 1) {
        searchParams.delete("page");
      } else {
        searchParams.set("page", page);
      }
      return searchParams;
    });
  }}
  renderItem={(item) => <PaginationItem {...item} />}
/>
```

[image: Edit updating-only-one-search-param-using-react-router-dom-link]

If you must use a `Link` component as the pagination item then it would seem the issue is trying to spread the `searchParams` object into a new `URLSearchParams` object, it doesn't correctly shallow copy the search parameters. Move the logic of computing a new search string ***outside*** the `to` prop.

Example:

```
<Pagination
  defaultPage={1}
  page={currentPage}
  count={pageCount}
  renderItem={(item) => {
    const search = createSearchParams(searchParams);
    if (item.page === 1) {
      search.delete("page");
    } else {
      search.set("page", item.page);
    }
    return (
      <PaginationItem
        component={Link}
        to={{
          pathname: ".",
          search: search.toString()
        }}
        {...item}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

[image: Edit updating-only-one-search-param-using-react-router-dom-link (forked)]

Comment: Thank you, but I specifically wanted the PaginationItems to be Links, because it allows users to open new pages in another tabs, and also seems more semantically correct to me.

Comment: @user9314872 I see. If the paginator "pips" are actually links, then yes, I'd agree with the semantic HTML correctness. I'll see if I can come up with another solution that satisfies that constraint.

Comment: @user9314872 Sorry for delay, I've updated my answer to include a working `Link` implementation. Please do check it out when you have time.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! I don't understand why it needs to be spread outside the `to` prop, but it works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not read your response correctly and can't edit my previous comment anymore. It works like a charm, but I do not understand why it can't be spread into new URLSearchParams object inside the `to` prop.

Comment: @user9314872 Oh, the issue wasn't that you were spreading `searchParams` in the `to` prop, it's that spreading the `searchParams`, e.g. `createSearchParams({ ...searchParams })`, wasn't working correctly at all, anywhere. The solution is to create a new `URLSearchParams` object in each "instance" of the `renderItem` callback and add/delete the `"page"` parameter. The reason this has to be done outside the `to` prop is because there are two steps that just aren't possible to do inline, (1) create URLSearchParams copy and (2) add/remove page parameter.

Comment: @user9314872 If the `URLSearchParams` objects implemented a functional programming pattern you could do something like `search: createSearchParams(searchParams).set("page", page).toString()`, but because the `set` method is a void return you can't chain any calls.

Comment: Ok. I think it makes more sense to me now. Thank you for the help.